# opencart 1.5 show count store in admin setting/store page

Tags: opencart

I'm using multistore in Opencart 1.5. I want to show the total number of store that I have made and I want to show it in the setting/store page. Can anybody help?

Comment: I know in controller/setting/store.php there is $store_total = $this->model_setting_store->getTotalStores();

So I'm trying to <?php echo $store['store_total']; ?> but dont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `$this->model_setting_store->getTotalStores()` will return the number of stores excluding the default store.
So total number of stores:

In controller add the line:

```
$this->data['total_stores'] = $this->model_setting_store->getTotalStores()+1;
```

In template file use it as below:

```
<?php
echo $total_stores;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

However, to get it working in the controller file and avoid any errors first you need to load your model:

```
$this->load->model('setting/store');
```